# Get change of variable environment from script python

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a python script, this run a set_env.sh file.
Later, I can get this new variable environment changed into set_env.sh
Is possible?

set_env.sh

```
var1="value1" var2="value2" var3="value3"
```

get_env.py

```
import os
os.system("set_env.sh")
print os.environ['var1']
```

Result: KeyError: 'var1'

I know that I can use os.environ['var1'] = 'value' (or set var env) into python file.
But I have access to this environment info only from shell file.

Can you help me?

Comment: When you run `env` from shell - do you see the variables setup?

Comment: print environment variables/values and read them into python

Comment: @programmerjake that's what `os.environ` does

Comment: @alfasin, thank for you reply. Yes, I modify set_env.sh and add echo $var1 and works fine.

Comment: @moylop260 `os.system` executes commands _in a subshell_.  Subshells, however, cannot modify the environment of the parent shell.  Thus, the changes that `set_env.sh` make will be forgotten as soon as `os.system` completes.

Answer (score 0):

My temp solution was

```
(?P<variable>[\w]*)[ ]*[\=][ ]*[\"|\']{0,1}(?P<value>[\w]*)[\"|\']{0,1}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3PMy7-GgOxl5dWHr)

```
        enviroment_regex = "(?P<variable>[\w]*)[ ]*[\=][ ]*[\"|\']{0,1}(?P<value>[\w]*)[\"|\']{0,1}"
        match_object = re.search( enviroment_regex, open("set_env.sh", "r").read() )
        os.environ[match_object.group("variable")] = match_object.group("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set an environment variable from python use:

```
os.environ["var1"] = "value1"
```

Pay attention that python spawns the environment, which means that the env will contain `var1` as long as you're in the python program. If you'll type from shell `env` (after running the program) there will be no recollection of `var1`.

For more info: https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-3/shell-environment-variables

Comment: My py script execute sh script.

Comment: @moylop260 yes but it executes it in a subshell which is closed right after the script finished its execution. I guess that the right question would be: what are you trying to do ? If you're depending on env variables in order parts of the python script - then use my answer.